# Lens makers formula

Tags: optics, visible-light, conventions, geometric-optics, lenses

I am using sign convention while deriving the lens makers Formula but, in doing so, I am Not getting the correct formula for it. But when i derive the same formula without sign Convention it gets derived easily. **Shouldn't we use Sign Convention to derive lens makers Formula?**
*(I have derived others Formula of optics with sign Convention and everytime I get the correct Formula but not in case of lens makers?)*

Here is the Derivation.

[image]

Comment: More on [sign conventions in optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+sign*+convention*+optics).

Answer (score 1):

You're using refraction formula to derive lens makers formula.
The thing is you don't need to use sign convention for deriving lens makers formula  because if you see the derivation of refraction formula sign convention is already used in it.

My teacher told me that :)